# Why select menu $invalid is always true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a HTML:

```
<form name="form">
     <select name="gender" ng-model="model" ng-required="true"
      ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur'}">
          <option value="" disabled>--Select--</option> 
          <option value="Male">Male</option> 
          <option value="Female">Female</option> 
     </select>
</form>

<form-error element="gender"><p>Please select Gender</p></form-error>
```

I am using angularJS javascript in a directive

```
.directive('formError', function() {
    'use strict';
     return {
        require: ['^form'],
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/partials/form-fields/validations/error.html',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr, form) {
            var element = $attr.element;

            $scope.form = form[0];

            $scope.$watch('form.' + element + '.$viewValue', function(newVal, oldVal){
            $scope.$dirty = $scope.form[element].$dirty;
            $scope.$valid = $scope.form[element].$valid;
            $scope.$invalid = $scope.form[element].$invalid;
            $scope.$value = newVal;

            console.log($scope.form.gender.$invalid);
         }, true);

         $scope.$watch('form.$submitted', function(newVal, oldVal){
             $scope.$submitted = newVal;
         }, true);
    }
});
```

Directive above links to this html page below

```
 <div class="input__error"
      ng-if="($dirty && $invalid && $value !== '') || ($submitted && $invalid)"
      ng-transclude></div>
```

The input text $invalid from true to false when i type in any text but on the select menu, I selected Male but it will still come as true for $invalid. I selected Female then it will become false for $invalid.

Basically if I select Male, the error should disappear.

Any Ideas why? Thanks

Comment: Please create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates problem

Comment: It may have something to do with the ng-required flag. Remember that Angular runs validation on page load. If there is a required field on a form and there is no value present, then it the form is immediately invalid

Comment: Where is this directive applied? Extrapolating from how you wrote it, I tried to reproduce - [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GAQWMnbR2U56L2ZZuRRp?p=preview), but it still shows `$invalid` correctly. And also, why do you have it - it seems rather redundant.

Comment: This directive is directed to the Error message, I update the code

Comment: ok if I do after i selected MALE console.log($scope.form.gender); - $invalid = false, console.log($scope.form.gender.$invalid); $invalid = true. I wonder why is that happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur'}
```

This was the issue that was causing my validation on the select menu, I just had to remove it.